# HttpListenerException when trying to listen to non-localhost target

Tags: c#, http, listener, httplistener

I am trying to listen to a certain endpoint, using the following code:

```
string url = "http://111.111.1.11:8080/";
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add(url);
listener.Start();
```

listener.Start() throws HttpListenerException: 'The format of the specified network name is invalid'

Researching the problem I tried the following solutions with no luck:

- Disabling firewall entirely
- Adding the url to listen list, and to urlacl using netsh http add commands (both of them)

Worth mentioning that the listener does work when i change the url to localhost.

Could there be some kind of constraints I am not aware of in my network?

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Is that IP address present on your machine?  IE does it show up when you run ipconfig?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft yes, it's a different IP in my solution that responds to pings and shows up in browsers

Comment: But is it an IP on the machine where you're running that code?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft it's an IP of a PC in my LAN

Comment: Then you're using the wrong type.  HttpListener is for listening to incoming HTTP requests on one (or all) of your local IPs.  You can't listen on another PC's IP address.  You can use WebClient to send request to an HTTP Listener running on that PC. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft so hang on, if I understand you correctly. lets say I want to listen to requests made to a server in the same network as I, it's not possible without making modifications in the server?

Comment: Correct.  Each server own its own IP addresses.

Comment: is it possible to use long polling in this scenario?

Comment: Has this issue ever been solved?